# why is my environment looking for cucumber in rake?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rake

I'm trying to execute cucumber on a Jenkins machine and I keep getting the following error

```
Gem::LoadError: Could not find cucumber (>= 0) amongst [rake-10.0.3]
to_specs at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency.rb:247
   to_spec at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency.rb:256
       gem at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems.rb:1231
    (root) at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/bin/cucumber:22
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

any idea what is going on here?

here is my gemlist if it helps

```
+ cd /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/bin
+ ls
ascii85
autospec
bundle
cucumber
cuke_sniffer.rb
htmldiff
ldiff
make_data.rb
nokogiri
oletool
parallel_cucumber
parallel_rspec
parallel_test
pdf_callbacks
pdf_list_callbacks
pdf_object
pdf_text
rackup
rake
rdebug-ide
restclient
rspec
sample
xlsopcodes
```